# Is it correct to load the webapp configuration in an application scope object?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, configuration, scope

I am new to Java EE for Web and I am creating a Java version for a REST microservice API, which I have versions for Delphi and PHP.

All of the API's configuration is stored in an Oracle Database and is compatible with all versions of this API architecture.

My goal is to load all the configuration only once, from the database to the API, and not on every request, to make thinks cheap and fast for the memory and CPU. The only moment when the API needs to reload the configuration is when I change any part of it (then the control panel will send a request for the API to reload the config from DB). These configurations are read-only by the API (*thread-safe*).

I ask those of you specialists in Java Servlets, if the right way to do that is by these steps:

1. Create a POJO for config structure;
2. Create a DAO to load this config into POJO;
3. Check if ServletContext does not have "myConfig" in Application Scope;
4. If it doesn't, then instantiate DAO and Write POJO into ServletContext as "myConfig";
5. Always get config through "myConfig" instead of instantiate DAO on every Request Scope.

Will I get better results with that approach, like:

- Less database connections;
- Less memory comsumption;
- Less CPU load for my Servlet requests; and
- More speed on each request?

*Note: I am using pure JavaEE with no frameworks, like Spring. (wanna keep it thin)*

*Obs: For those who didn't get what I'm talking about, it's like the problem case: how to show in the homepage how many users are online right now.*

Comment: How are you loading the `myConfig`? `HashMap`?

Comment: MyConfig is just an attribute name I gave to store the POJO already with the database's content.

Comment: The `POJO` contains data like `CORS` *origin list, microservices names and parameters, users allowed to access admin panel* etc.